How to download the rmaxent package from Github in R
Issue
I want to produce a presence only species distribution model using the Maxent technique. I have found an online tutorial that exactly fits the type of analysis that I want to embark on.
I am trying to download the package rmaxent from Github and I am having some issues.
Here's another source to obtain the latest version or rmaxent, but I couldn't get this function to work either.
If anyone can help, I would like to thank you in advance.
R-code: Attempt 1
#install the package maxent
library(devtools)
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("johnbaums/rmaxent")

Error Message
Using GitHub PAT from the git credential store.
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 401.
  Bad credentials

  Rate limit remaining: 59/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2024-10-08 10:42:59 UTC

R-code: Attempt 2
# download maxent.jar 3.3.3k, and place the file in the desired folder; note that, there may be a newer version of Maxent
if( !file.exists(paste0(system.file("java", package="dismo"),"/maxent.jar"))  )   {
  utils::download.file(url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrmaxent/Maxent/master/ArchivedReleases/3.3.3k/maxent.jar",
                       destfile=paste0(system.file("java", package="dismo"),"/maxent.jar"),
                       mode="wb") ## wb for binary file, otherwise maxent.jar can not execute
}

#Open the library rmaxent
library(maxent)

Error Message
Error in library(package, pos = pos, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE,  : 
  there is no package called ‘maxent’

R-Code: Attempt 3
install.packages("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrmaxent/Maxent/master/ArchivedReleases/3.3.3k/maxent.jar", repos = NULL, type="source")

Error Message
trying URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrmaxent/Maxent/master/ArchivedReleases/3.3.3k/maxent.jar'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 673246 bytes (657 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 657 KB

Error in rawToChar(block[seq_len(ns)]) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\024\0\b\0\b\0\xdclO?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\004\0META-INF/\xfe\xca\0\0\003\0PK\a\b\0\0\0\0\002\0\0\0\0\0\0\0PK\003\004\024\0\b\0\b\0\xdclO?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\024\0\0\0META-INF/'

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/4p/9pwl2nwj6h7glyzr26kvwr2w0000gn/T//Rtmp5t168W/downloaded_packages/maxent.jar’ had non-zero exit status


Look at the dismo package. It has maxent also

I cannot reproduce this error, all worked fine with me.

Thanks for getting back to me Rui. You managed to download the package mrmaxent. If I'm getting these error messages, do you know what the problem be? Would you mind sharing your R-code with me? Attempt 1 only downloads 'remotes', not 'rmaxent' for me. Many thanks for your time

What about downloading the release package (https://github.com/johnbaums/rmaxent/releases/download/v0.1.1/rmaxent_0.1.1.tar.gz) and install it with install.packages(path_to_file, repos = NULL, type="source")? The other option would be to download the whole repository (in RStudio - File -> New Project -> Version Control -> Git) and build it by yourself.

Hello Grzegorz, I followed your advice and I tried to install the package the way you first suggested and I got the error message in attempt 3. When you say rebuild it yourself, do you mean run all the R code written by John Baums so I can use the functions in the tutorial? Many thanks for your time as I'm a novice

Since you are getting the "Bad credentials" error, that means you have a bad github personal access token stored somewhere. See the duplicate for how to remove it. Then remotes::install_github("johnbaums/rmaxent") should work just fine.

Hello Mr Flick, I followed the instructions by following the link provided. I tried Sys.getenv("GITHUB_PAT") and the output was [1] "".  I don't know what this means

I then tried gitcreds::gitcreds_set() and I was given a selection:1: Abort update with error, and keep the existing credentials; 2: Replace these credentials; 3: See the password / token. It doesn't matter what section I choose, this process doesn't do anything and the selection menu asks me to choose a selection again.

I then did some trouble shooting with this link https://happygitwithr.com/https-pat.html?q=credential#pat-troubleshooting and I couldn't find the bad token

I don't understand how to solve this issue. I would be deeply appreciative if anyone that has commented has any ideas. Many thanks

Thank you everyone! I found the bad token and I managed to delete it and download rmaxent using gitcreds_delete(). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction
